# Is there a bookmarklet that will let me add a Delicious link in one click?

Tags: delicious, bookmarklet

I use Delicious.com and want a bookmarklet that just adds a link with a specific tag in one click, rather than bringing up the new link window and requiring me to enter tags and click enter. Does anyone know where I can get this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, almost - in two clicks actually :)

[Lazy Sheep](http://ejohn.org/apps/sheep/) is "a del.icio.us bookmarklet that auto-tags and auto-describes your bookmarks".

It allows you to set up custom tag (or several if I understood correctly) and other parameters and generate bookmarklet for them. So you can have different bookmarklets with different parameter sets. When you're logged into Delicious, clicking bookmarklet moves you to Delicious.com with already filled form of adding new bookmark. If you don't want to change anything, you just press Save and this is the second click. After that it returns you to bookmarked page or stays at Delicious - this behaviour is optional too. I checked and it worked as described. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

[Historio.us](http://historio.us) has this feature.
The idea is to not bother tagging your bookmarks, just "historify" them with a single click and then use google-search to find stuff you want later.
I use it and love it.

Comment: And the search feature makes tags look really obsolete!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a little off-topic (it's more about the browser than the web app itself), I wanted to have a look. The bookmarklet code (for Chrome in this instance) looks like this:

`javascript:(function(){f='http://delicious.com/save?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'&v=5&';a=function(){if(!window.open(f+'noui=1&jump=doclose','deliciousuiv5','location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'))location.href=f+'jump=yes'};if(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)){setTimeout(a,0)}else{a()}})()`

I think you need to find out what string to add in, probably around the `&v=5` - maybe something like `&tag=mytag`? I don't use delicious, otherwise I'd give it a go.